# Case when along with sum

Tags: sql, oracle, max, case-when

There is an extra payer called workers comp and I am trying to making it as a Workers Comp/Liability by doing case when statement. I am trying to return a single line of row. Your help will be really appreciated.

Here is my query:

```
select distinct
    case when payer.class like 'Workers%' 
        then 'Workers Comp/Liability'
        else Payer.class
    end as Payer,
    sum(Payment.payment_at) AS SumOfPmt
from Payer inner join Payer.payerid = Payment.payerid 
where payer.class like 'Workers%'
Group By payer.class
```

Result:

`Payer                    |     SumOfPmt
Workers Comp/Liability    |     558.76
Workers Comp/Liability    |     167036.41`

What I want:

`Payer                   |      SumOfPmt
Workers Comp/Liability   |      167595.17`

Comment: You are getting 1 row for each distinct `payer.class` just as you requested with that GROUP BY. You aren't displaying that `payer.class` column, so it's difficult to tell, but that's whats happening. Instead you want to aggregate on the result of that CASE statement, so just `GROUP BY payer` or `GROUP BY <same case statement here>`. Or toss the unaggregated SELECT statement into a subquery and run your GROUP BY on that.

Comment: Yes. I have two unique payers ('Workers Comp' and 'Workers Comp/Liability') but they should just be just one Worker Comp/Liability, meaning 'Workers Comp' was a typo on the system and I can't find a way to sum them into a single row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would repeat the same `CASE` expression with `GROUP BY` clause :

```
select (case when p.class like 'Workers%' 
             then 'Workers Comp/Liability'
             else p.class
        end) as Payer,
       sum(pay.payment_at) AS SumOfPmt
from Payer p inner join 
     Payment py
     on p.payerid = py.payerid 
where p.class like 'Workers%'
group by (case when p.class like 'Workers%' 
               then 'Workers Comp/Liability'
               else p.class
          end);
```

You don't need to use `DISTINCT` since it has `GROUP BY`.

Comment: You nailed it. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a simpler form of your query:

```
select 'Workers Comp/Liability' as Payer,
       sum(pm.payment_at) AS SumOfPmt
from Payer py inner join
     Payment pm
     on py.payerid = pm.payerid 
where py.class like 'Workers%';
```

Your `WHERE` clause and `CASE` expression are doing the same thing.  Only one is necessary.